# Как сделать смену кнопок play/close?

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать, чтобы при *click* на кнопке *play* данная кнопка скрывалась и отображалась кнопка *close*, а когда закрываю видео, кнопка *close* скрывалась и появлялась кнопка *play* ?

```
<section class="section_1">
    <div id="wideo">
           <div id="play">
               <i class="far fa-play-circle"></i> (кнопка плей)
           </div>
           <div id="close">
               <i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i> (кнопка клозе)
           </div>

           <iframe style="display: none;" id="video" width="100%" 
           height="100vh" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-yQ8kxikSJQ" 
           frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" 
           allowfullscreen></iframe>
          <a href="http://127.0.0.1:49217/index.html"></a>       
     </div>
 </section>


#play {
    color: #fff;
     position: absolute;
     font-size: 60px;
     left: 48%;
     top: 50%;
     cursor: pointer;
     transition: all 0.5s ease;
   }

#close {
    color: #fff;
     position: absolute;
     top: 5px;
     left: 84%;
     font-size: 25px;
  }

.section_1 {
    background-image: url(image/video_image.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh; 
    position: relative;
}

$('#close').find('#play').on('click', function() {
  $('#video').slideToggle(function(){
       if($('#close')){
           $('#close').hide();
       } 
  });
});
```

Comment: задавая вопрос в русскоязычном сообществе не пренебрегайте изучением русского языка

Comment: @Alex, в незалежной он под запретом.

Comment: `$('#close').find('#play')` - подразумевает, что элемент `play` находится внутри элемента `close`

Comment: я js вообще не шарю, потому и написал..

Comment: @VladSpirin -I want a flying pony. *Danny Maccabee:* I want a flying pony, too, but they don't exist. *Michael:* Then I want a regular pony. And I want to name him Nelson. *Danny Maccabee:* How about a PlayStation 3 and we name him Nelson?

Comment: вопрос подразумевает, что нужно запускать видео при нажатии на *play* и останавливать при нажатии на *close* или это сами можете сделать ?

Comment: @alex спасибо вам большое, скрипт работает)!

Comment: @СаняБортнюк если ответ Вам помог, отметьте его как решение, для этого нажмите на серую галку слева от ответа, галка станет зеленой, что будет означать, что ответ Вам помог и является решением Вашего вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1:** отображение/скрытие *play*/*close* происходит независимо от выполнения *slideToggle()*.

```
$('#play, #close').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#video').slideToggle();
    $('#play, #close').toggle();  
});
```

```js
$('#play, #close').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#video').slideToggle();
    $('#play, #close').toggle();  
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #444;
}

#play {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 60px;
  left: 48%;
  top: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#close {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 84%;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.section_1 {
  background-image: url(image/video_image.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section_1">
  <div id="wideo">
    <div id="play">
      <i class="far fa fa-play-circle"></i> (кнопка плей)
    </div>
    <div id="close">
      <i class="fas fa fa-times-circle"></i> (кнопка клозе)
    </div>
    <iframe style="display: none;" id="video" width="100%" height="100vh" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-yQ8kxikSJQ?r=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <a href="http://127.0.0.1:49217/index.html"></a>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Вариант 2:** отображение/скрытие *play*/*close* происходит после выполнения *slideToggle()*. Чтобы ответ не был копией другого, добавлен старт/стоп видео в *iframe* при нажатии на кнопки.

(!) В сниппете не работает, работает на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amateur009/03gzcnoe/17/).

(!) Для работы в ссылку на видео необходимо добавить параметр, например `r=0`: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/-yQ8kxikSJQ?r=0`

```
$('#play, #close').on('click', function(e) {
    let obj = this; //e.target.id может работать нестабильно
    let video_src = $("#video").attr('src').replace(/\&autoplay\=\d+/, '');
    $('#video').slideToggle(function(){
      $('#play, #close').toggle();
      $("#video").attr('src', video_src + ((obj.id == 'play') ? '&autoplay=1' : ''));
    });
});
```

```js
$('#play, #close').on('click', function(e) {
  let obj = this; //e.target.id может работать нестабильно
  let video_src = $("#video").attr('src').replace(/\&autoplay\=\d+/, '');
  $('#video').slideToggle(function(){
    $('#play, #close').toggle();
    $("#video").attr('src', video_src + ((obj.id == 'play') ? '&autoplay=1' : ''));
  });
  
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #444;
}

#play {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 60px;
  left: 48%;
  top: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#close {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 84%;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.section_1 {
  background-image: url(image/video_image.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section_1">
  <div id="wideo">
    <div id="play">
      <i class="far fa fa-play-circle"></i> (кнопка плей)
    </div>
    <div id="close">
      <i class="fas fa fa-times-circle"></i> (кнопка клозе)
    </div>
    <iframe style="display: none;" id="video" width="100%" height="100vh" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-yQ8kxikSJQ?r=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <a href="http://127.0.0.1:49217/index.html"></a>
  </div>
</section>
```